# Rails database design for a model which can be used by one of many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a model named `feedback` with attributes, rating and review. A `product` may have a feedback, a `appointment` may have a feedback, a `user` may have a feedback.

I could add individual fields, like user_id, product_id, appointment_id in the feedbacks table, but that does not seem to be a very good scalable solution. The other option in my mind is to use a generalized, reference_id field, and a reference_model field which can be populated with the model name converted to string, and then I could manually interpret if the id entered in reference_id belongs to a user, product or an appointment.

What would be the best way of going about associating each feedback with any one of the 3 models, at a given time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read about [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

There's even a nice [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association).